# non paid load testing tools java based

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing

What are the java-based open source performance testing tools available except JMeter? Tools which are written in java and free to use?

over the internet searched a lot but showing locust, k6, Tsung, LoadNinja, etc which are not java based. Need to know a few tools like JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more or less popular and "big" projects they are:

- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/)
- [The Grinder](https://grinder.sourceforge.net/)

In case you need more - you can i.e. perform your own search on Github  like https://github.com/topics/load-testing?l=java and filter results according to your tool selection criteria.

Comparison of JMeter, Gatling and Grinder: [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools)